# Query string state/province field

Tags: profile, jquery

On a profile listing page, you can query string to pre-select the field. e.g. add `&state_province-Primary=NN` where NN is the ID in the civicrm_state_province table.

However, on a profile create page, specifically on a contribution page, this does not work.

How can we make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the jQuery tag, I assume you're open to a jQuery solution.

- [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/how-to-get-url-parameter-using-jquery-or-plain-javascript) covers pulling a variable from a URL argument.
- Then it's just a matter of identifying the CSS identifier of the field you want to fill (right-click, use "Inspect Element") and referencing it.  E.g.:

```
var state = GetURLParameter('state');
$('#state_province_id-2').val(state);
```

The [Select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) suggests this should work on Select2 widgets as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer is a Civi extension that uses the `buildForm` hook to prepopulate the field.  Here's some example code that does something very similar on a custom field:

```
function trackingcodes_civicrm_buildForm( $formName, &$form ) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main' ||
      $formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm' ||
      $formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_ThankYou' ) {
    CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addStyleFile('trackingcodes', 'trackingcodes.css');
  }
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main') {
    if (isset($_GET['track1'])) {
      $defaults['custom_180'] = $_GET['track1'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['track2'])) {
      $defaults['custom_181'] = $_GET['track2'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET['track3'])) {
      $defaults['custom_182'] = $_GET['track3'];
    }
    $form->setDefaults($defaults);
  }
}
```